# Trello checklists

Tags: trello

I have topics as my lists, i.e  - PR, Marketing, Comms 
Projects are listed as cards under each heading and in turn each card has a checklist.

I'd like to turn checklist items into cards on a Daily To Do list without removing the check list point on the card - how do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is not available in Trello.

Trello has integrations called [Power-Ups](https://trello.com/power-ups). Have a look at the [board utility ones](https://trello.com/power-ups/category/board-utilities), there may be something there that will improve your workflow, such as the [The Card Repeater Power-Up](https://trello.com/power-ups/57b47fb862d25a30298459b1/card-repeater) which automates the creation of Trello cards for repeated tasks.